# Нужно получить символ из консоли (уже выведенный) С++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Очень долго искал как это сделать, но и то что нашел не работает.

```
char get_char_at_xy(int x, int y)
{
    CHAR_INFO ci;
    COORD xy = { 0, 0 };
    SMALL_RECT rect = { x, y, x, y };
    return ReadConsoleOutput(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &ci, 1, xy, rect)
        ? ci.Char.AsciiChar
        : '\0';
}
```

Жалуется что не может преобразовать Int в _COORD И SMALL_RECT в PSMALL_RECT

Может есть другие реализации?

Comment: ¿Ну а что мешает в этом примере передать в функцию правильные аргументы?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Создайте внутри функции переменную типа `COORD` и присвойте значение `{1, 1}`, а насчет `PSMALL_RECT`, то нужно передавать указатель на структуру, а не значение, так что перед `rect` нужно написать `&`.

Вот пример вашей функции с изменениями:

```
char get_char_at_xy(int x, int y)
{
    CHAR_INFO ci;
    COORD xy = { 0, 0 };
    //Размер буфера в виде строк и столбцов
    COORD buff_size{ 1, 1 };
    SMALL_RECT rect = { x, y, x, y };
    return ReadConsoleOutput(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &ci, buff_size, xy, 
        /*Передаем указатель на структуру*/&rect)
        ? ci.Char.AsciiChar
        : '\0';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Работает!